# Toggle a body class based on active slide using Cycle2

Tags: jquery, css, dom, jquery-cycle2

Hi Stack Overflow peeps,

I don't have working code for this, as I'm unsure where to even begin. So apologies in advance.

I've scoured the internet for a solution but this feels like it could either be really simple (and I'm over complicating things) or it's somewhat specialised.

---

**Current Situation**:
I'm using [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) as my slider of choice (and would prefer to stick with that - will be difficult to make me go with another slider, TBH). Each slide will have a specific "colour" class, as well as a 'slide' class

**What I need**:
I need to change a class on the `<body>` based on the active class' colour.

**Thoughts**: 
So I don't have a naming convention yet for the colour classes, but my thought was it could be something like `.col-[name]` were *[name]* is yellow, red, etc. So when the active class of the slider is *col-yellow*, it adds this class to the `<body>`, and therefore I can add a background colour/image (whatever CSS I want) to the body.

Then once the active slide changes and if it happens to change its body class to something like *col-red*, then the `<body>` matches.

I hope this makes sense and is something some awesome person out in Stack Overflow land can help me with.

---

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similar question not that long ago.

DEMO  http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/7VzaQ/3/

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-before', function (event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
var bg = $(incomingSlideEl).find('img').css('backgroundColor');
$('body').css('background', bg);
});
```

Hope this helps

[edited] I've edited the code so now it assigns the same class to the body that is assigned to the active slide

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/7VzaQ/4/

Just to explain what i did - As you can see in the above code i creat a `var` called `bg`. This `var` is the CSS background color of the active slide. I then assign that `var` to the background of the body tag. As you requested you wanted a class change, not just a style change. In light of this i simply changed the code so that it is finding the `attr` `class` rather than the CSS background color.

Var Snippet before:

```
var bg = $(incomingSlideEl).find('img').css('backgroundColor');
    $('body').css('background', bg);
```

Var snippet after:

```
var bg = $(incomingSlideEl).find('img').attr('class');
$('body').attr('class', bg);
```

Comment: Any chance you could rewrite this so it isn't based on the background-colour of an image in the slider? I'm hoping for a class (as described in my original post) or even a data attribute perhaps? I'm trying to re-write what you've posted and I think I'm just butchering it :D

Comment: Still working through this. I promise to tick the answer once I've got it fully implemented (project for a client in my spare time). Haven't forgotten about you! :D

Comment: Hi Vector, I have one last question (sorry for the delay) - how would I make this work without it replacing all of the classes in the <body>? I've tried to work around it, but I *really* need the original classes I've got happening in the body to not be overwritten. I tried toggling the class, but for obvious reasons it isn't working. It needs to know what class to remove, and add the new one on its own. Thanks in advance if you get a chance to help again!

Comment: It's not good practice to assign so much to the body element. My approach would be to create a wrapper within the body tags and assign this background effect to that. this way it gives you far more control.`<body>< div class="wrapper"> //html here </div><body>`